# Error during applying bartlett test in my function

Tags: r, anova, kruskal-wallis

I am a rookie in R, and just start to write function in R. My purpose is to create a function to improve the process of checking variation and further conduct ANOVA or Kruskal wallis test, also calculated the mean or median of significant item.

```
Result<- function(variable, group, database){
  variable <- database$variable
  group <- database$group
  R1 <- database%>%
    bartlett.test(x= variable, g= group)
  R1
  if(R1>=0.05){ #ANOVA is suitable
    z <- aov(variable, group, data=database)
    zx<-summarize(z)
    zxc<- unlist(zx)['Pr(>F)1']
    if(zx<0.05){ #if result of ANOVA smaller than 0.05 then calculate the mean
      R2 <- database%>%
        group_by(group)%>%
        summarize(mean(variable))%>%
        print()
      R3 <- TukeyHSD(z, "variable")
      R3
      }
    }else{#k-w is suitable
      q <- kruskal.test(variable, group, data=database)
      qw <- q[["p.value"]]
      if(qw<0.05){
        R4 <- database %>%
          group_by(group) %>%
          summarise(mean(variable))%>%
          print()
        R5 <- dunnTest(variable, group, method="bonferroni", data= database)
        R5
      }
      }
}
```

After I put my variables into my function, the error showed up

```
Error in complete.cases(x, g) : no input has determined the number of cases
12.
complete.cases(x, g)
11.
bartlett.test.default(., x = variable, g = group)
10.
bartlett.test(., x = variable, g = group)
9.
function_list[[k]](value)
8.
withVisible(function_list[[k]](value))
7.
freduce(value, `_function_list`)
6.
`_fseq`(`_lhs`)
5.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
4.
eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env)
3.
withVisible(eval(quote(`_fseq`(`_lhs`)), env, env))
2.
database %>% bartlett.test(x = variable, g = group)
1.
Result(PCtoopday, patho, nmlab_PCintendedLC_forpatho)
```

I've looked it up for a while, the complete.case() is all TRUE in my variables.
I can't figure out what is wrong in my function, also not sure about other part of my function can work out...hope you guys can help me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem results from how you extract a column of `data.fram` in a function. You can compare the following two example. The former fails when extracting `Species` column of `iris` dataset, but the later works.

```
fun <- function(data, var){
  return(data$var)
}

fun(iris, Species)
# NULL
```

```
fun <- function(data, var){
  return(data[[var]])
}

fun(iris, "Species")
# [1] setosa  setosa  setosa  setosa  setosa
# ...
```

---

Therefore, you need to revise your function like this:

```
Result<- function(variable, group, database){
  variable <- database[[variable]]
  group <- database[[group]]
  ...
}
```

And execute it with **quoted** `variable` and `group` arguments.

```
Result("PCtoopday", "patho", nmlab_PCintendedLC_forpatho)
```

Comment: thank you for your reply
the effect of [[ and $ were the same in data.frame, both of them get a list, right?
I've tried it and input the function with " "


`variable <- database$variable`
`group <- database$group`
`variable <- database[[variable]]`
`group <- database[[group]]`


but the result seemed to be the same

`Error in complete.cases(x, g) : no input has determined the number of cases`

Comment: @洪宇亮 The both codes I showed have different results. The `$` symbol doesn't work in a function. How do you execute your function? Do you add quotes around variable and group? I.e. `Result("PCtoopday", "patho", nmlab_PCintendedLC_forpatho)`